# Entering value in database

Tags: database, python-3.x, sqlite

```
import easygui as eg
import sqlite3

# ----------------------------------------------------
# Enabling connection to database
conn = sqlite3.connect('ATM.sqlite')
print("Connected to database successfully")
conn.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists Info(ID INTEGER, Name TEXT, Address TEXT, Mobile_no INTEGER, PIN INTEGER, "
             "Balance INTEGER)")



def Admin_AddUser():
    options = ['ID', 'Name', 'Address', 'Mobile No.', 'PIN']
    Current_bal = 0
    values = eg.multenterbox('Enter the information for new user', 'Add User', options)
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO Info (ID, Name, Address, Mobile_no, PIN, Balance)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"),[values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4], Current_bal]


loop = True
while loop:
    ch1 = eg.buttonbox('Welcome to the ATM portal, continue as you desire', '', ['Admin', 'Customer', 'Exit'])
    if ch1 == 'Admin':
        AdminPortal()

    else:
        loop = False

# Terminating connection to database
conn.commit()
conn.close()
print("Terminated connection to database successfully")
```

Error:
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 6, and there are 0 supplied.
Why is it showing this error? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake in closing bracket. Else, you line of code is so big and maybe difficult to see mistake. The small code below is more easily to understand

```
 sql = "INSERT INTO Info (ID, Name, Address, Mobile_no, PIN, Balance)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
 values = [values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4], Current_bal]
 conn.execute(sql, values)
```